# Cross-Validation: Include IV which are significant in one model but insignificant in the other?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, cross-validation, group-differences, model-comparison

I ran regression analyses using SAS with two different data sets containing *different individuals* but *exactly the same IV and DV*: let's call them "low_deviance" and "high_deviance" and I would like to assess, whether there is a significant difference in the predictive power of the IV.

Probably there is no such difference, but I just want to try out several methods checking this intuition...

**What I have already tried:**

- *Beta Coefficients:* 95 % confidence intervals show no significant difference between the beta coefficients of the two models/samples.
- *R²:*
  Using the computer program “R2” (http://www.statpower.net/Software.html#R2) in a DOSBox I calculated 95 % confidence intervals for the determination coefficients of the two models/samples, too. These were overlapping again revealing no significant difference between the two models.

**What I am trying to do now:**

- *Cross-Validation:*
  Following Tabachnick & Fidell (2013: 140 ff.) I want to use the regression equation resulting from the data set “low_deviance” to calculate estimated values for the DV with the individuals from the data set “high_deviance”.

  Then I correlate the estimated values of the DV with the real values of the DV (1) for the data set “low_deviance” (estimated with the “correctly corresponding” equation gained from this data set) and (2) for the data set “high_deviance” (estimated with the regression equation gained from the “wrong” data set “low_deviance”).

  The higher the first correlation (data set used: “low_deviance”; regression equation used: “low_deviance”) the better is the predicive power of the model because the estimated values correspond well with the real values.

  The higher the second correlation (data set used: “high_deviance”; regression equation used: “low_deviance”) the better the regression equation of the data set “low_deviance” also predicts the real values of the data set “high_deviance”, i. e. the more the regression equation of the data set “low_deviance” is generalizable to the data set “high_deviance”. A low correlation would indicate that the regression equation from the data set “low_deviance” does not adequately predict the real values of the data set “high_deviance” which means that the groups of individuals (data sets, samples) differ in some relevant respect...

And I could repeat the procedure vice versa.

Now here is the question: **What do I do with IV which are significant in one model but insignificant in the other?**

Do I always use all IV ignoring their significance in the different models/samples?

Do I only use IV which yield significant beta coefficients in both models/samples?
Alternative ideas?

I will gladly clarify my question if necessary.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The idea of a variable being significant in one setting and not in another is a misuse of $P$-values.  For your original question it would be better to combine the two samples and to do a combined test of whether any of the IVs interact with the low/high deviance variable.  Keep to the original variable scales when judging such interactions (i.e., you are assessing differences in slopes).  BTW what made the datasets be divided in the first place?

Comment: Thank you, Frank, for commenting so quickly!
I understand your objection concerning the misuse of p-values.
I've already tried to use interaction terms. The problem is that I have one moderator variable and several interacting IV which results in a hardly interpretable output.
The moderator variable was gained from calculations measuring the degree of deviance from a norm. It was used to divide the two data sets (= extreme groups one std left and right from the mean).
Do you have any other idea to test this moderation with several interacting IV?

Comment: The output of a regression containing interaction terms is hardly interpretable in my case because the rationale behind all this is: "If a person has an inconsistent understanding of certain values such as self-direction or tradition (i. e. high deviance), then these value-IV (e. g. self-direction or tradition) loose some of their predictive power." I think an insignificant interaction term is ambivalent: Is the interaction insignificant or does a value like tradition loose its significance in combination with deviance...?

Comment: Nicolas, division of the data into "high" and "low" based on an underlying continuous quantity is not a good idea, and you will have residual variation hidden by that approach.  I would develop a combined model using the most raw continuous form of the moderator variable.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I will not pursue this analysis further. I have to give a talk about my recent results tomorrow in front of other sociologists. Maybe they will criticize me in a constructive way and suggest new approaches. ;-) Thank you very much! Great website here!

Comment: I hope that sociologists recognize the perils of dichotomania.